# Unable to find out what the data directory is for PostgreSQL in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, postgresql

I hava PostgreSQL 9.3 installed by homebrew in Mac OS X 10.9.3. When I first installed it, it worked well. After reboot it happened to be not launched and I don’t know how to launch by `pg_ctl` it because I can't find out what its data directory is:

```
$ pg_ctl start
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.

$ pwd
/usr/local/var/postgres

$ ls -al
total 96
drwx------  21 alex  admin    714 Jun  2 21:23 .
drwx------   3 alex  admin    102 Jun  1 15:08 ..
-rw-------   1 alex  admin      4 Jun  1 15:08 PG_VERSION
drwx------   6 alex  admin    204 Jun  2 11:40 base
drwx------  42 alex  admin   1428 Jun  2 14:18 global
drwx------   3 alex  admin    102 Jun  1 15:08 pg_clog
-rw-------   1 alex  admin   4465 Jun  2 10:58 pg_hba.conf
-rw-------   1 alex  admin   1636 Jun  1 15:08 pg_ident.conf
drwx------   4 alex  admin    136 Jun  1 15:08 pg_multixact
drwx------   3 alex  admin    102 Jun  1 18:24 pg_notify
drwx------   2 alex  admin     68 Jun  1 15:08 pg_serial
drwx------   2 alex  admin     68 Jun  1 15:08 pg_snapshots
drwx------   7 alex  admin    238 Jun  2 21:23 pg_stat
drwx------   2 alex  admin     68 Jun  2 21:23 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------   3 alex  admin    102 Jun  1 15:08 pg_subtrans
drwx------   2 alex  admin     68 Jun  1 15:08 pg_tblspc
drwx------   2 alex  admin     68 Jun  1 15:08 pg_twophase
drwx------   4 alex  admin    136 Jun  1 15:08 pg_xlog
-rw-------   1 alex  admin  20571 Jun  1 15:08 postgresql.conf
-rw-------   1 alex  admin     79 Jun  1 18:24 postmaster.opts
-rw-------   1 alex  admin   1482 Jun  2 21:23 server.log
```

In `/Library` there is nothing titled `PostgreSQL` or something.

How do I find it out?

**UPDATE**:

```
$ sudo chown -R _postgres /usr/local/var/postgres
$ ls -ld /usr/local/var/postgres
drwx------  21 _postgres  admin  714 Jun  2 21:23 /usr/local/var/postgres

#################

$ sudo -u _postgres pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -w start
could not identify current directory: Permission denied
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid": Permission denied

$ ls -al /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
ls: /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid: Permission denied

$ sudo ls -al /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
ls: /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid: No such file or directory
```

Comment: PostgreSQL version? Installed from where, and how? (Links). Mac OS X version?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp  `SHOW data_directory;` did you try ??

Comment: @hector, no I didn't try. How can I try it if it's not launched!

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp its the query that you can use via `pgAdmin`

Comment: or you can get your data directory path with the same `query` using `psql`

Comment: @hector, doesn't pgAdmin require running postgresql?

Answer (score 4):

`pg_ctl` doesn't look in the current directory for the datadir. You have to specify it with the `PGDATA` env var or the `-D` command line argument.

To launch:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -w start
```

however, you should really set it up to start using `launchd`. AFAIK it's covered in the Homebrew documentation.

Comment: the error - `sudo -u _postgres pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -w start
Password:
could not identify current directory: Permission denied`

Comment: `pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid": Permission denied`

Comment: `ls -ld /usr/local/var/postgres`

Comment: `drwx------  21 alex  admin  714 Jun  2 21:23 /usr/local/var/postgres`

Comment: Looks like you `initdb`'d the datadir as your own user not the `postgres` user, so the `postgres` user doesn't have the right to access it and run. That's probably why it's failing to autostart if you added it to launchd too. `chown -R postgres /usr/local/var/postgres` should do the job.

Comment: That ... doesn't make a ton of sense. Path looks fine, permissions look fine, why's it complaining? `pg_ctl` doesn't like that it doesn't have permission to see the current directory (your homedir) - try running from / or /usr/local/var/postgres . But that shouldn't cause the errors shown.

Comment: What funny is that `$ cd /usr/local/var/postgres
-bash: cd: /usr/local/var/postgres: Permission denied`.

Comment: I reinstalled it using this https://gist.github.com/lxneng/741932. I worked fine. After reboot I got the same error. But I was able to run by `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres` and not `pg_ctl`. I wonder, why?